# Easiest way to deploy a simple AWS Beanstalk PHP app without any PHP frameworks, using RDS + ElastiCache for data

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Hope someone can point me. Google doesn't yield much that's simple to understand (there's stuff like Pheanstalk, etc), and [Amazon's own Beanstalk documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP_eb.html) as always is woefully arcane presuming that we use Laravel or Symfony2.

We have a simple set of 10 PHP scripts that constitute our entire "website", with fast functional programming. In our testing this has been much faster than doing the same things with needless OOP. Anyway, with PHP 7, we're very happy with the simple functional code we have.

We could go the EC2 route. Two EC2 servers load balanced by ELB. Both EC2 servers just have Nginx running with PHP-FPM, and calling the RDS stuff for data (ElastiCache for some caching speed for read-only queries).

However, the idea is to lower management costs for EC2 by relying on Beanstalk for the simple processing that's needed in these 10 PHP scripts.

Are we thinking the right way? Is it simple to "upload" scripts to Beanstalk in the way we do in EC2 via SSH or SFTP? Or is that only programatically available via git etc?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily replicate your EC2 environment to Elastic Beanstalk using Docker containers.

Create a Docker container that contains required packages (nginx etc), any  configuration files, and your PHP scripts. Then you'd deploy the container to Beanstalk.

With Beanstalk, you can define [environment variables](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html) that are passed to underlying EC2 instances where you application is running. Typically, one would use environment variables to pass, for example, the RDS hostname, username, and password to the Beanstalk application.

Additionally, you can store the Dockerfile, configuration files, and scripts in your git repository for version control, and fetch them whenever you create the container.

See AWS documentation about [deploying beanstalk application from Docker containers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.html).

Comment: Thank you Olli. I was trying to avoid the Docker containers. It's a bit technical for me. Is that the only way?

Comment: @PKHunter Well, the other way would be using a pre-configured PHP 7 environment for Beanstalk. There's tutorial for that use case in the [Beanstalk documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/php-ha-tutorial.html).